# RunTimeError w/ for row in cursor

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, cursor

Every time I execute this, I get a runtime error pointing to my "for row in cursor," stating that A column was specified that does not exist. Any ideas how to fix this?

```
import arcpy
import os

gdb = r'C:\Users\Stephanie\Documents\SPRING20\PGIS\project1\usa_cities.gdb'
feature_class = "largest_cities"

fc = os.path.join(gdb, feature_class)
print(fc)

fields = ['NAME', 'POP2017']

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[2] != None:
            print("City: " + str(row[2]) + " Population: " + str(row[9]))
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I think you are trying to access fields that you don't specify, in this case you can access only `row[0` for `NAME` field, and `row[1]` for `POP2017` field. You are using index greatest that 1, that is a mistake. If you want to retrieve all fields use `*` instead,

`with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, '*') as cursor:`

BTW, , for performance and order it is recommended to specify the fields.

Comment: I believe what you're trying to say is that indexing of fields rows from an arcpy.da.SearchCursor is 0 based, which is absolutely correct, also if you've specified the fields with a list then *only the specified fields* can be accessed so trying to grab str(row[9]) isn't going to work if there have only been two fields requested.

Comment: @MichaelStimson thanks, that's what I was trying to point.