# Using search cursors with SQL in Python

Tags: sql, cursor, search

I'm trying to create a search cursor that will list the cities in which the population is greater than 1,000,000. I was able to create a list of the cities and their populations, but unsure of the issue with my syntax.

this executed correctly:

```
import arcpy
import os

gdb = r'C:\Users\Stephanie\Documents\SPRING20\PGIS\project1\usa_cities.gdb'
feature_class = "largest_cities"

fc = os.path.join(gdb, feature_class)
fields = ['NAME', 'POP2017']
desc_list = []

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, '*') as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[2] != None:
            print("City: " + str(row[2]) + "     Population: " + str(row[9]))
```

> **this is where my issue is**

```
fields = ['NAME', 'POP2017']
desc_list = []

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, '*') as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[2] != None:
            print("City: " + str(row[2]) + "     Population: " + str(row[9]))
#Error:
  File "<ipython-input-46-956655ed0551>", line 6
    if '"POP2017" > 1000000'
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: The error message doesn't match your code, can you copy/paste your snippet into the ArcCatalog python window and see if you still get an error; some IDEs get stroppy with arcpy commands, to get around this use the python window to execute the commands. Is your field POP2017 a numeric field or a string field? Consider using string.format like print("City: {}      Population: {}'.format(row[2],row[9])) - simple text concatenation gets difficult to read when multiple variables are used.

Comment: It's not particularly safe to make positional assumptions unless you provide the field list as an input array (not a singleton `'*'`). If you want to constrain the list to `POP2017 > 1000000` you should apply that as a `where_clause`.

Comment: POP2017 is a numeric field. I originally was trying to specify my fields, but was advised to use  [*] to access all my fields, which is how I was able to get my first cell to actually execute. I'm quite new to using python so am struggling to get the correct syntax. That question is linked here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/351710/runtimeerror-w-for-row-in-cursor

Comment: You were advised "for performance and order it is recommended to specify the fields." I am recommending the the same.  Generate the list from a `ListFields` or however you like, but using a *splat* query increases the risk that the query behavior will change unexpectedly, corrupting the hard-coded column radix values.